# My clash royale troops and other supercell games are very blurr

Tags: clash-royale

[image: clash royale weird graphics]

Why is this happening it has less graphics and low quality

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with some devices.
Write to Supercell support for steps to fix.
(Or they may let you know your device is not supported.)